# DNS Server is flooded with localhost resolution

Tags: networking, security, dns, internet-security, denial-of-service

I have a public DNS server and can be accessible by anyone. Recently we have been flooded with thousands of DNS queries trying to resolve a "localhost" such as these:

[image: example of one of the query]

Is this supposed to be intended behavior. Is there something I can do to avoid such attacks?